# .NET Need solutions to copy all references automatically (NuGet) to Server Side

Tags: c#, .net, reference, publish

I have a problem with missing reference (NuGet[.dll]) files after publishing my website to server. I solved it by "right-click" at the missing file in "reference folder" and selected "Property", then I set the "Copy Local" to "true" and everything worked fine after that.

The problem is: How to set the project to always publish website with copying all reference files to server?

I don't need to always set the properties of all reference to "true". Do you have any solutions to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about doing this but generally what you've done is what most people end up doing since it's the easiest option.

1. You can set them to "copy local" which is what you've done. This in turn means that the dependent dlls are copied to the working directory. During runtime and when it comes to assembly resolving, one of the paths the framework will walk is the current (executing) directory and if it can find the dlls there, it will try to load them. To make this easier, you could potentially copy all your binaries to a common location for all projects and have their dependencies to be copied there as well (by setting the build path to something common like ..\bin or whatever). At least this way you don't end up copying the same dll multiple times.
2. If these dlls are signed, you can try to install them into GAC. That's amongst the first places CLR will look in. If you do this, you only have to install them once and you can use them from any .NET application on that machine.
3. A more complex solution would be to have these on a network share somewhere or in a different folder that's deployed with your app. This solution is quite involved though since not only you'll run into security problems (which can be circumvented using caspol) but also you have to resolve the assemblies yourself by listening to the appropriate event (which I can't remember) when assembly loading fails and loading them yourself. This solution will not be easy but it's possible.

There are other more advanced things you can do with assemblies like defining your own bindings, etc. but they won't really help with your question.

I recommend reading this which should give you some ideas about what options are available to you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx